# How to return a readonly copy of a collection

Tags: c#, collections, properties, readonly

I have a class that contains a collection. I want to provided a method or property that returns the contents of the collection. It's ok if calling classes can modify the individual objects but I do not want them adding or removing object from the actual collection. I have been copying all the objects to a new list, but now I'm thinking that I could just return the list as IEnumerable<>.

In the simplified example below is GetListC the best way to return a read only version of a collection?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<string> mylist;

    public MyClass()
    {
        mylist = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(string toAdd)
    {
        mylist.Add(toAdd);
    }

    //Returns the list directly 
    public List<String> GetListA 
    { 
        get
            {
            return mylist;
            }
    }

    //returns a copy of the list
    public List<String> GetListB
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string st in this.mylist)
            {
                returnList.Add(st);
            }
            return returnList;
        }
    }

    //Returns the list as IEnumerable
    public IEnumerable<string> GetListC
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.mylist.AsEnumerable<String>();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`List(T).AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx):

```
return this.mylist.AsReadOnly()
```

which will return a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

Comment: It's in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace.

Comment: Huh, I'm surprised I messed that one.

Comment: Of course you'll need to replace the return type from List<String> to ReadOnlyCollection<string> or ICollection<string> or IEnumrable<string>

Answer (score 2):

Just use ReadOnlyCollection class, it is supported since .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic ReadOnlyCollection class (`Collection.AsReadOnly()`). It doesn't copy any objects which may have some strange results when the underlying collection is changed.

```
        var foo = new List<int> { 3, 1, 2 };
        var bar = foo.AsReadOnly();

        foreach (var x in bar) Console.WriteLine(x);

        foo.Sort();

        foreach (var x in bar) Console.WriteLine(x);
```

But if you don't want a copy, that's the best solution.

Answer (score -2):

I prefer returning IEnumerable, but you don't need to cast.  Just do

```
public IEnumerable<string> StringList { get { return myList; }
```

`List<string>` is an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: The problem with that is it becomes very expensive to do things like determine the count.

Comment: The real problem is that the consumer of the code can anytime cast it back to List<T> and modify the list.

Comment: you don't always need the count, and the point is to expose an interface that gives you all the functionality you need, and none you don't